# \\имя_хостового_компьютера\temp

Tags: администрирование, windows-server

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, с учебным заданием.

> Создать исполняемый файл, производящий
> копирование любого файла из дериктории
> C:\cd\ объемом более 2 Мбайт на ресурс
> \\имя_хостового_компьютера\temp с
> поддержкой продолжения копирования при
> обрыве.

Используется Windows Server 2003. Имя хостового компьютера - srv-x. При попытке выполнить команду

```
copy 1.txt \\srv-x\temp
```

получаю ошибку

> The network path was not found.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как задать этот \temp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там короче нужно было нажать "Manage Your Server" и создать файловый сервер с именем "temp"